# Localhost didn't send any data?

Tags: node.js

when a user is logged in the login page redirects to dashboard but when an admin or manager logs in it should redirect to admin page or manager page.
tried this method but it is showing localhost didnt send any data
please help

users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
//login handle
router.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('login');
})
router.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('register')
    })
//Register handle
router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=>{
passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect : '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash : true
})(req,res,next)
})
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const {ensureAuthenticated,authRole,authMan} = require('../config/auth') 
//login page
router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('welcome');
})
//register page
router.get('/register', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('register');
})



router.get('/dashboard',ensureAuthenticated,authRole(User.isAdmin),authMan(User.isManager),(req,res)=>{
        res.render('dashboard',{
            user: req.user
        });
})
module.exports = router;
```

auth.js

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated : function(req,res,next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg' , 'please login to view this resource');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    },
    authRole : function(isAdmin){
        return (req, res, next) => {
            if (req.user.isAdmin == true) {
              res.redirect('/admin');
            }
        
            next()
          }
        },
        authMan : function(isManager){
          return (req, res, next) => {
              if (req.user.isManager == true) {
              
                res.redirect('/manager');
              }
          
              next()
            }
          }
    
}
```

passport.js

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},(email,password,done)=>{
            //match user
            User.findOne({email:email})
            .then((user)=>{
                if(!user){
                    return done(null,false,{message:'email not registered'});
                }
                //math passwords
                bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,(err,isMatch)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(isMatch){
                        return done(null,user);
                    } else{
                        return done(null,false,{message: 'password incorrect'});
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
        })
    )
    passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) {
        done(null,user.id);
    })
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
        User.findById(id,function(err,user){
            done(err,user);
        })
    })
}
```

please suggest some other methods too for a user,admin and manager login
Thanks